# Are negative charges sinks and positive charges sources, or is it an arbitrary choice?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-field-theory

Classical Electromagnetism defines negative charges as sinks and positive charges as sources.

Is it based on experimental distinction, or is it just that one kind of charge must be thought of as a source and the other as a sink? Will this distinction even have any effect in the mathematics?

What if there were three charges, for example, like the colour charge? How is/could it modelled?

Comment: It is as you expected, arbitrary. Whichever is chosen to be a source, the other is then a sink. For colour charge, red is a source and anti-red is a sink, and so on for the other two colours.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I see, so there are 6 colour charges and 2 normal charges. I guess that is a suitable answer!

Comment: You have to flip the right hand rule for the left hand rule. The story goes that Wigner would solve EM by flipping the signs and using the left hand rule because his left hand was free while his right hand was writing. At the end he flipped it all back around...

Comment: @JonCuster A simple flip doesn't seem to be doing the trick, you'll have to flip it in two axes.. I googled for references, and I only found another Physics SE comment from you :P

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Your comment should be an answer